# Associate data tables and automatically updating them in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically, I've got 3 data tables. "jobs", "periods", and an associated table "JobPeriodAssociation".

Now, the JobPeriodAssociation displays every possible combination of jobs and periods. E.g. i've got 2 jobs (j1, j2) and 2 periods (t1, t2), the table will display 4 rows: j1t1, j1t2, j2t1, j2t2.

If I now add a period in the "periods" table, it automatically updates the "JobPeriodAssociation" table by adding a (predefined) 3rd period/job combination. I.a. j1t1, j1t2, j1t3, j2t1, j2t2, j2t3.

This is accomplished by a change action in the periods_controller

```
def change
@mynumber_of_periods = params[:mynewnumber].to_i
@number_of_periods = Period.count
number_of_missing_periods=@mynumber_of_periods - @number_of_periods

if number_of_missing_periods > 0
  @jobs = Job.all
  @nanns = Nann.all
  (1..number_of_missing_periods).each do |number|
    name="t#{number+@number_of_periods}"
    @new_period=Period.create!(name: name)
    @jobs.each { |jo|
      JobPeriodAssociation.create(job_id: jo.id, period_id: @new_period.id, apples: 2, bananas: 2, milk: 2, beer: 2)
    }
  end
end
```

(+obviously some minor alterations in routes and the index views)

When creating a job, I create it with several params (see the image attached here: [TABLES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Q751.png)) As of now, the params don't get pushed to the JobPeriodAssociation table and I only figured out a way how to hard code them as can be seen in the first listing of this topic

```
    @new_period=Period.create!(name: name)
    @jobs.each { |jo|
      JobPeriodAssociation.create(job_id: jo.id, period_id: @new_period.id, apples: 2, bananas: 2, milk: 2, beer: 2)
    }
```

As a result, every newly created entry in the JobPeriodAssociation table has the params 2, 2, 2, 2.
However, I would like to push the created jobs including its params to the JobPeriodAssociation as displayed in the image attached. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You have three tables and you have associations between them? Could you include details explaining the structure of that association, It is hard for me to understand and maybe is it cause by some lack of information.
What is the association between jobs, periods and JobPeriodAssociation?

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio Well the table "JobPeriodAssociation" has the following model: belongs_to :job belongs_to :period while each of them "has_many" :JobPeriodAssociations.
If you look at the image that I posted, you can see how they work together. And now I try to understand how to create the "red arrows" in the image that i uploaded. How can I "mirror" the params from one table in another table?

Comment: Do you want me to write you a reply and explain you how to get the fields from jobperiodsassociations table by using the Job model and viceversa, how to find the entry from jobs based on the one from jobperiodassociation? Or maybe I did not understand well and I will read better your post.. sorry

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio yes. i would like to fill the jobperiodassociation table with the entry from the job table.

Comment: You can do that with a foreign_key. There is no need to physically fill the table. It would only slow down your system, while you can access the data with the Model. You should read about this.

Comment: So do you have an update?

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio I'm still working on it... Will definitely let you know as soon as I got results. Right now I'm still trying to wrap my head around how to properly implement the foreign_key method.

Comment: It is very simple, just follow the documentation. I have seen people getting problem by not following the documentation i linked to you.
You will need to create a migration. for creating or changing the tables:
`create_table :jobperiodassociations do |t|
t.belongs_to :job, index: true
t.belongs_to :period, index: true
end`

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio yaaay! It worked! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. For any problem just ask me Fabrizio

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio One more thing, any thoughts on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749752/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror-in-userscontrollercreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you though of doing a Join between Period and Job, which would be JobPeriodAssociation?
Maybe I misunderstood your problem, I tell I am sorry. Please let's discuss it to help you solve it.

[image]

You can get a better idea of what i mean at the following link:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

If this is the problem your are trying to solve, then the best best way is a has_many though JobPeriodassociation. This is the link to the full explanation.

The join would consist in the following

Job Model

```
has_many  :jobperiodassociations
```

Period Model

```
has_many :jobperiodassociations
```

JobPeriodAssociation

```
belongs_to :job
belongs_to :period => all the entries of jobperiodassociations will be retrieved with the foreign key job_id in jobperiodassociations
```

Instances of job:

```
job = Job.new
job.jobperiodassociations = [] => all the entries of jobperiodassociations will be retrieved with the foreign key job_id in jobperiodassociations
```

Instances of period

```
period = Period.new
period.jobperiodassociations = []
```

Instances of jobperiodassociations have two foreign keys, one for job and one for period.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association