# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in UsersController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I know this has been asked a million times before but the suggested solutions didn't fix anything for me.

```
def create
@user = User.new(user_params)   
if @user.save
else
  render 'new'
end
end
```

At first I had these params:

```
private

def user_params
 params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :name, :email, :password,
                             :password_confirmation, role_ids: [])
end
```

Then I tried allowing every param:

```
private

def user_params
 params.require(:user).permit!
end
```

However, the result is the same:

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in UsersController#create

```
  def sanitize_for_mass_assignment(attributes)
    if attributes.respond_to?(:permitted?) && !attributes.permitted?
      raise ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
    else
      attributes
    end
```

What am I missing?!

```
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]

Rails 4.2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright so here we go, I had a messed up gem file installed. Problem Solved.